# "%FF" Directory Error? Seems to be due to touch [C]

Tags: c, string, file-io

I'm working on a C project where the user can make a blog directly through the program. I'm setting up my output HTML and CSS files and can't seem to fix this error I'm getting.

To be clear, the compiler issues no errors or warnings.

**The error is this**: For some (not all) blog titles I input, the directory name becomes is appended with `%8B%FF`, or just `%FF`, or some other variation, but always ending with `%FF`. This folder contains no files and cannot be deleted until the computer has been restarted. When the error does not appear, files are present in the folder.

I've included most of my code because I truly do not understand this error. **I believe the error to be at the bottom of `CreateNewBlog()`, where I call for the creation of HTML and CSS files. Without these lines, the error does not occur.**

So, what does the `%FF` mean at the end of my directories and why is it there?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void CreateNewBlog();
void NewBlogHTML(char path[92], char blog_title[64]);
void NewBlogCSS(char path[92], char blog_title[64]);

int main()
{
  CreateNewBlog();

  return 0;
}

void CreateNewBlog()
{
  char blog_title[64];
  char dir_name[64];
  char mkdir[70];
  char touch[70];
  char html_path[92];
  char css_path[92];
  int i = 0;

  printf("Enter blog title: ");

  fgets(blog_title, 64, stdin);
  blog_title[strlen(blog_title) - 1] = '\0';  // removes trailing '\n' from fgets()

  for (i = 0; blog_title[i]; i++) {           // convert "Blog Title" to "blog-title"
    if (blog_title[i] == ' ') {
      dir_name[i] = '-';
    } else dir_name[i] = tolower(blog_title[i]);
  }

  dir_name[strlen(dir_name)] = '\0';

  sprintf(mkdir, "mkdir %s", dir_name);
  system(mkdir);

  sprintf(touch, "touch %s/index.html", dir_name);
  system(touch);

  sprintf(html_path, "%s/index.html", dir_name);
  sprintf(css_path, "%s/style.css", dir_name);
  NewBlogHTML(html_path, blog_title);  // HERE IS THE PROBLEM (when uncommented)
  NewBlogCSS(css_path, blog_title);    //
}

void NewBlogHTML(char path[92], char blog_title[64])
{
  FILE *index = fopen(path, "w");
  // html file text
  fclose(index);
}

void NewBlogCSS(char path[92], char blog_title[64])
{
  FILE *style = fopen(path, "w");
  // css file text
  fclose(style);
}
```

Comment: `dir_name[strlen(dir_name)] = '\0';` is bogus. strlen() counts upto the first '\0', so there is no need to put a '\0' there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one problem:

```
for (i = 0; blog_title[i]; i++) {           // convert "Blog Title" to "blog-title"
  if (blog_title[i] == ' ') {
    dir_name[i] = '-';
  } else dir_name[i] = tolower(blog_title[i]);
}
```

The last character written to `dir_name[]` is never `'\0'` because the loop body doesn't execute when `blog_title[i]` is `'\0'`.

You need to explicitly append `'\0'` to `dir_name[]`. If you don't, `dir_name[]` may contain garbage after all the written characters to it and only then at some point, by pure chance, will it have `'\0'`, which can be part of the return address from the function or part of another variable stored on the stack.

Another, unrelated oddity is here:

```
sprintf(html_path, "%s/index.html/", dir_name);
```

Why is the file name ending in `'/'`?

Comment: The trailing slashes have been eliminated and I added the line `dir_name[strlen(dir_name)] = '\0';` after the loop and the problem still persists. Same error.

Comment: That's not a very smart fix. Think. How does `strlen()` work? It looks for a `'\0'` and counts characters before it. But you haven't yet written `'\0'` into `dir_name[]`. So, this line will (hopefully) find some `'\0'` (possibly, very long after the valid characters written into `dir_name[]`) and overwrite it with `'\0'`, changing exactly nothing. You want `'\0'` in `dir_name[]` immediately after the last char written in the loop. You could use `strlen(blog_title)` or `i` as the position of where to write `'\0'`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 for (i = 0; blog_title[i]; i++) {           // convert "Blog Title" to "blog-title"
    if (blog_title[i] == ' ') {
      dir_name[i] = '-';
    } else dir_name[i] = tolower(blog_title[i]);
  }

   dir_name[i] = '\0'; // <<-- Add this line
```